# Flex - Clearing DateField value on tab change in TabNavigator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, datefield, tabnavigator

I have the following tab navigator, which has a **Project** tab, containing a **Combobox** next to **Release** label as follows(**AdditionalDetails.mxml)**:
[image]

Same tab navigator is having a **Gate2** tab, which contains a **DateField** next to the label **CERT load date**, which can be seen below(**Gate2.mxml**):
[image]

Now, when I select **Release** as **TBD** on **Project** tab, an alert box appears as follows:
[image]

On clicking **YES**, I want to clear the **DateField** on **Gate2** tab. How can I do so?
Code for Combobox(AdditionalDetails.mxml):

```
<mx:ComboBox id="General_Release_Dates"
                     selectedItem="{modelProxy.General_Release_Dates}"
                     valueCommit="{model.General_Release_Dates = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;updateReleaseDate(event)}"
                     change="{model.General_Release_Dates = event.currentTarget.selectedItem;updateReleaseDate(event)}" close="closeHandler(event);" includeInLayout="true" visible="true">
        </mx:ComboBox
```

Code for handling YES click on Alert box:

```
private function alertClickHandler(evt:CloseEvent):void {
if (evt.detail == Alert.YES) { //Code to clear DateField}
```

**DateField** code on **Gate2** tab(**Gate2.mxml**):
DateField code:`<mx:DateField  id="G2_CRTLoadDate" width="150" selectedDate="{modelProxy.G2_CRTLoadDate}" change="{modelProxy.G2_CRTLoadDate = event.currentTarget.selectedDate;changeManagerStatus()}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated: Aug 31 23:27(JST)**

If you're using singleton
[Flex - Problems in accessing static variable on another mxml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220118/flex-problems-in-accessing-static-variable-on-another-mxml-page)

1) Create variable at your MySingleton class like below.

```
    private var _gate2:Object;

    public function set gate2(value:Object):void
    {
        _gate2 = value;
    } 

    public function get gate2():Object
    {
        return _gate2; 
    }
```

2) Gate2.mxml (write at creationComplete event)

```
singleton.gate2 = this;
```

3) Control Gate2 from external class.

```
private function alertClickHandler(evt:CloseEvent):void {
    if (evt.detail == Alert.YES) {
        //Code to clear DateField

        singleton.gate2.G2_CRTLoadDate.selectedDate = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: On using "singleton.gate2.G2_CRTLoadDate.selectedDate = null;, I'm getting the following error: "1119: Access of possibly undefined property gate2 through a reference with static type ttds.cmt.extra:MySingleton.
Here, MySingleton.as is my actionscript file, which is inside ttds.cmt.extra package.

Comment: Did you define "private var _gate2:Object;" in your MySingleton class?
and "singleton.gate2 = this;" at your Gate2 creationComplete event.

Comment: Uno Just did and it worked. Thanks a lot once again to you and best wishes. You saved my job :)